# Django-filters how to create dynamically filterset_fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-filter, django-filters

I wrote a viewset, which depends on the endpoint:

```
ALLOWED_ENTITIES = {
    'persons': [Person, PersonSerializer, '__all__'],
    'locations': [Location, LocationSerializer, ('country', 'city', 'street')],
    'institutes': [Institute, InstituteSerializer, ('number', 'name_short', 'mail_domain')],
}

class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = '__all__' #should be ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][2]

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][0]
        return model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][1]
        return serializer
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('aim:api-root'))),
    url(r'^api/(?P<entity_name>\w+)', EntityListView.as_view({'get': 'list'})),
    url(r'^/admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and it works as expected, when i go to /api/persons it shows me viewset with Person Model and PersonSerializer.

But the problem, that i dont know how to define `filterset_fields = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][2]` and i can not use `filterset_fields = '__all__'` because i get the following error: `Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for field 'aim.Department.parent'.` where `'aim.Department.parent'` is ForeignKey. Perhaps someone knows how to dynamically define `filterset_fields`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer, the `filterset_fields` could be overridden in `get_queryset`:

```
class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = '__all__'

    def get_queryset(self):
        model = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][0]
        self.filterset_fields = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][2]
        return model.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        serializer = ALLOWED_ENTITIES[self.kwargs['entity_name']][1]
        return serializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this filterset_fields method.

```
class EntityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]


    @property
    def filterset_fields(self):
        app_label, model_name = self.kwargs["app_label.model"].split(".")

        model_cls = apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
        if issubclass(model_cls, models.Model):
            # filters for model fields
            fieldset = {
                field.name: [
                    "exact",
                    "gt",
                    "gte",
                    "lt",
                    "lte",
                    "in",
                    "iexact",
                    "startswith",
                    "istartswith",
                    "endswith",
                    "iendswith",
                    "regex",
                    "iregex",
                    "isnull",
                    "contains",
                    "icontains",
                    "ne",
                ]
                for field in [
                    field
                    for field in model_cls._meta.get_fields()
                    if field.get_internal_type()
                    not in [
                        "JSONField",
                        "ForeignKey",
                        "ManyToManyField",
                        "OneToOneField",
                    ]
                ]
            }

            # filters for model relations
            for field in [
                field
                for field in model_cls._meta.get_fields()
                if field.get_internal_type()
                in [
                    "ForeignKey",
                    "ManyToManyField",
                    "OneToOneField",
                ]
            ]:
                fieldset[field.name] = [
                    "exact",
                    "gt",
                    "gte",
                    "lt",
                    "lte",
                ]
            return fieldset
        else:
            return {}


def get_queryset(self):
    app_label, model_name = self.kwargs["app_label.model"].split(".")

 
    if issubclass(model_cls, models.Model):
        return model_cls.objects.all()
```